# Nautilius Launcher Icon

Tags: nautilus, icons

I am looking for a clean png/svg version of the icon displayed displayed in launcher of nautilus (the drawer). Is there any official place I can download it or do I have to make a screen shot and crop itmyself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the drawer icon of nautilus is:

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/128/system-file-manager.svg
```

The name of the icon file is system-file-manager.svg

If you want to find icons of other applications, you need to find the name of the icon file and then search for the icon file in the `/usr` directory. To find the name of an icon file, browse in Files to `/usr/share/applications`, select an application, and drag the application icon into the open window of a graphical interface text editor like Text Editor (gedit) or Emacs. The text editor will show you information about the application, and in the line that starts with `Icon=` is the name of the icon file.